# Что означает - устройства (device) OEM?

Tags: android, терминология, oem

Иногда попадается следующая терминология без уточнений, а именно `device OEM`. Что означает `OEM`?

Answer (score 1):

`OEM` - `Оriginal Equipment Manufacturers` (производители оригинального оборудования).

Если вы разрабатываете на `Windows` и хотите подключить устройство к тестированию, вам необходимо установить соответствующий драйвер `USB`. На [этой странице](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html) приведены ссылки на веб-сайты для нескольких производителей оригинального оборудования (`OEM`-производителей), где вы можете загрузить соответствующий `USB`-драйвер для своего устройства.